# Android-Camera intent isn't locate photo in specific folder

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera

I have small problem with my android application. My application taking picture by invoke the standard android camera intent:

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, this.myURI);

startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

After the application return from the camera intent, i try to look for the photo in the directory i store it (by the code), and the photo isn't there. The photo there just **when i close my application and open it again**.

I though maybe the folder is lock by me so the camera intent can't put the new photo there.

Please, any help??

(I don't know if someone have ever asked that (didn't really know what to look for), if so, please let me know)

Comment: Post the stack trace of the exception.

Comment: No exception, the photo just doesn't appear :(

Answer (score 0):

After you come back try to put this line

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://"+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

This line do a "refresh" and after the phone recognize the news photos saved in your phone.